# Querying a mysql database in a web project throughout a different domain than localhost retrieves no data

Tags: mysql, spring

Trying to understand why is happening this. When I query a different domain that I setted up on hosts file is like the data from the database is not being retrieved. I have a personal project with angular, spring-boot and mysql.  Angular query an API that is exposed by Spring that is querying mysql. When I run the project and I go to the URL localhost:8080 I get all the information, but when I go to mysite.com:8080 seems that all the data from mysql is not retrieved.

I modified the file hosts like this

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 

127.0.0.1 myownproject.com
```

and I granted all the privileges on mysql to the database mydb for the user@mysite.com

here is my spring configuration for the database

```
#override the spring parameter 'create-drop', 'create' creates the schema deleting the previous data
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database=H2

database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expediente_electronico
database.username=user
database.password=user
```

Thank you

Comment: `database.url=jdbc:mysql://http://myownproject.com` is this a typo or what you have in the config?

Comment: that's the config. i have it like this `dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mywebbapp`

Comment: maybe you can try without http?

Comment: thank you @Devon I tried both, I removed the http (was a typo error) but didn't work

Comment: thank you @RandykaYudhistira I leave it localhost, but still the same.

Comment: @agusgambina, strange.  What about using an IP?  `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost?  I'm not sure why it would be that way though.

Comment: @Devon thank you I tried with 127.0.0.1 still not working

Comment: why is this tagged angular? am removing the tag, has nothing to do with db paths

Comment: I was not sure how to explain how it works, but the web project is all contained in a jetty (spring boot) project, there I have three modules, one that is the parent, then the backend, and the front end. In the front end I am serving an API with spring that is queried with angular over http requests. But I am pretty sure that angular has nothing to do with the problem. thank you @charlietfl

Comment: are mysql dbm and your spring app on the same machine? you sure that you cant acces the data from database by your spring api  not just your app endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix the problem. I post the answer just in case is useful for someone else.

In the front end (in angular) I have http requests that have the url

```
http://localhost:8080/restservice
```

I changed this angular request to this url

```
http://myownproject.com:8080/restservice
```

Just works fine (obviously stop working for the previous URL). I am not sure, but I can imagine that this was because Spring allow the request for the given URL in the browser, but then when Angular tried to request a different URL wasn't allowed, that's why the data wasn't retrieved.